# This will compile correctly however it says there is nothing to run in two different IDE

Tags: java

This will compile correctly however it says there is nothing to run in two different IDE. What seems to be the issue here. I have added lines to just print hi to troubleshoot but still nothing.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

//Creates class
public class project42 {
    static class ExThread extends Thread {
        //Variables are set
        Semaphore sema;
        String theName;

        //
        public ExThread(Semaphore sema, String theName) {
            super(theName);
            this.sema = sema;
            this.theName = theName;
        }

        public void run() {
            //test For Westbound
            if (this.getName().equals("Westbound Cars")) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(theName + " are waiting");
                    sema.acquire();
                    System.out.println(theName + " are attempting");
                    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Westbound: " + i + " is waiting");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Westbound: " + i + " has crossed");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    System.out.println(exc);
                }
                System.out.println(theName + " has crossed the bridge");
                sema.release();
            } else {
                //Test for eastbound
                System.out.println(theName + " are waiting");
                try {
                    System.out.println(theName + " are waiting");
                    sema.acquire();
                    System.out.println(theName + " are attempting");
                    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Eastbound " + i + "is crossing");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("Eastboud " + i + " is crossed");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    System.out.println(exc);
                }
                System.out.println(theName + " have crossed the bridge");
                sema.release();
            }
        }

        //main class
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.print("hi");
            Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(1);
            //creates cars
            ExThread et1 = new ExThread(sema, "Westbound Cars");
            ExThread et2 = new ExThread(sema, "WEastbound Cars");
            //runs program
            et1.start();
            et2.start();

            et1.join();
            et1.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to run, since your main is in the inner class (ExThread). It needs to be in the outer class (project42).

Comment: I have tried moving it and have no success

Comment: O I'm sure that there will be more than only that problem since you never managed to run the code before, but moving the main will definitely solve the problem mentioned in the question. If you still can't make it run in your IDE, then you probably need to resolve something in your IDE. Cant tell you what, I can't see your IDE.

Comment: this is the only file it is struggling with. so i do not think the problems are with the ide